# Fabric.js: How to draw a polygon by mouse

Tags: fabricjs

I want draw a `fabric.Polygon` with mouse interaction in Fabric.js.
I made a small jsfiddle to show my actual state: http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/ujefxh7w/

After pressing the ESC key, the "interactive draw mode" is canceled and the polygon is finalized. But now the position of the polygon is wrong (controls are right).

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: As far as other solution works it's going to cause you problems with bounding box and repositioning the polygon. Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769421/wrong-border-coords-on-draw-a-polygon-with-the-fabric-js for solution and explanation and http://jsfiddle.net/orian/dyxjkmes/1/ for example.

Comment: https://github.com/taqimustafa/fabricjs-polygon Please check this demo i made for drawing polygon from mouse. If you have any question you can let me know.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for an updated answer that uses fabricjs 3.

FabricJS had a lot of changes, one of them being to the _calcDimmensions method. It no longer stores the values minX and minY on the object. It instead returns an object with the following:

```
  {
    left: minX,
    top: minY,
    width: width,
    height: height
  }
```

So with that in mind, the solution updates to the following:

```
currentShape.set({
points: points
});
var calcDim = currentShape._calcDimensions();
currentShape.width = calcDim.width;
currentShape.height = calcDim.height;
currentShape.set({
    left: calcDim.left,
    top: calcdim.top,
    pathOffset: {
        x: calcDim.left + currentShape.width / 2,
        y: calcDim.top + currentShape.height / 2
    }
});
currentShape.setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problem definition

When the polygon is added as static object (in sense that the points won't be modified) it's `left, right, minX, minY, width, height` and center point can be calculated based on provided points.

But when one wants a polygon to be created dynamically the problem arises.
After calling `setCoords()` it calculates the locations of the move boxes but it's based on the incorrect information about width and height.

**Remember**, when creating 1 point Polygon, it has width and height equal to 0, and the top left is equal to that one point.

## Solution

### First, correct the size

`_calcDimensions()` calculates `width`, `height`, `minX` and `minY` of the polygon. `minX` and `minY` are the minima in all points.

This informs us how far left and top above the old center some points were placed. We should use this information to move the old left to the correct spot. The new top-left point is the old center point translated by the `minX` and `minY` information.

```
var oldC = polygon.getCenterPoint();
polygon._calcDimensions();
polygon.set({
  left: oldC.x + polygon.get('minX'),
  top: oldC.y + polygon.get('minY')
});
```

### Fix points

After the center has moved by some vector `v` (a result of changing `left`, `right` and `width`, `height` properties). We need to updated all points by a reverse of `v`.

```
var newC = polygon.getCenterPoint();
var moveX = -(newC.x-oldC.x);
var moveY = -(newC.y-oldC.y)
var adjPoints = polygon.get("points").map(function(p) {
  return {
    x: p.x + moveX,
    y: p.y + moveY
  };
});
```

Check following Fiddle for the full example: http://jsfiddle.net/orian/dyxjkmes/5/

```js
/**
 * fabric.js template for bug reports
 *
 * Please update the name of the jsfiddle (see Fiddle Options).
 * This templates uses latest dev verison of fabric.js (https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/all.js).
 */

// initialize fabric canvas and assign to global windows object for debug
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// Do some initializing stuff
fabric.Object.prototype.set({
  transparentCorners: false,
  cornerColor: 'rgba(102,153,255,0.5)',
  cornerSize: 12,
  padding: 7
});

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE
var mode = "add",
  currentShape;

canvas.observe("mouse:move", function(event) {
  var pos = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
  if (mode === "edit" && currentShape) {
    var points = currentShape.get("points");
    points[points.length - 1].x = pos.x - currentShape.get("left");
    points[points.length - 1].y = pos.y - currentShape.get("top");
    currentShape.set({
      points: points
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});

canvas.observe("mouse:down", function(event) {
  var pos = canvas.getPointer(event.e);

  if (mode === "add") {
    var polygon = new fabric.Polygon([{
      x: pos.x,
      y: pos.y
    }, {
      x: pos.x + 0.5,
      y: pos.y + 0.5
    }], {
      fill: 'blue',
      opacity: 0.5,
      selectable: false
    });
    currentShape = polygon;
    canvas.add(currentShape);
    mode = "edit";
  } else if (mode === "edit" && currentShape && currentShape.type === "polygon") {
    var points = currentShape.get("points");
    points.push({
      x: pos.x - currentShape.get("left"),
      y: pos.y - currentShape.get("top")
    });
    currentShape.set({
      points: points
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});

    fabric.util.addListener(window, 'keyup', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        if (mode === 'edit' || mode === 'add') {
          mode = 'normal';

          var points = currentShape.get("points");
          points.pop();
          currentShape.set({
            points: points
          });

          var oldC = currentShape.getCenterPoint();
          currentShape._calcDimensions();

          var xx = currentShape.get("minX");
          var yy = currentShape.get("minY");
          currentShape.set({
            left: currentShape.get('left') + xx,
            top: currentShape.get('top') + yy
          });

          var pCenter = currentShape.getCenterPoint();
          var adjPoints = currentShape.get("points").map(function(p) {
            return {
              x: p.x - pCenter.x + oldC.x,
              y: p.y - pCenter.y + oldC.y
            };
          });
          currentShape.set({
            points: adjPoints,
            selectable: true
          });

          canvas.setActiveObject(currentShape);
          currentShape.setCoords();
          canvas.renderAll();
        } else {
          mode = 'add';
        }
        currentShape = null;
      }
    })
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

## Copy&paste

```
function fixPoly(poly) {
  var oldC = poly.getCenterPoint();
  poly._calcDimensions();
  poly.set({
    left: poly.get('left') + poly.get("minX"),
    top: poly.get('top') + poly.get("minY")
  });

  var pCenter = poly.getCenterPoint();
  poly.get("points").forEach((p) => {
    p.x -= pCenter.x - oldC.x;
    p.y -= pCenter.y - oldC.y
  });
  poly.setCoords();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this problem, which are very very simple:

#### Solution #1

Just remove the polygon from the canvas and recreate it (using new fabric.Polygon(...)) on every added point!

*Pros & Cons*: Yes, you will get a slightly worse performance, because the canvas will be rerendered twice, but you will save yourself the trouble of recalculating the coordinates every time.

You can check this solution out in the snippet below or in [this forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1fvxx6L/2/).

```js
/**
 * fabric.js template for bug reports
 *
 * Please update the name of the jsfiddle (see Fiddle Options).
 * This templates uses latest dev verison of fabric.js (https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/all.js).
 */

// initialize fabric canvas and assign to global windows object for debug
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// Do some initializing stuff
fabric.Object.prototype.set({
  transparentCorners: false,
  cornerColor: 'rgba(102,153,255,0.5)',
  cornerSize: 12,
  padding: 7
});

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE
var mode = "add",
  currentShape;

canvas.observe("mouse:move", function(event) {
  var pos = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
  if (mode === "edit" && currentShape) {
    var points = currentShape.get("points");
    points[points.length - 1].x = pos.x;
    points[points.length - 1].y = pos.y;
    currentShape.set({
      points: points
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});

canvas.observe("mouse:down", function(event) {
  var pos = canvas.getPointer(event.e);

  if (mode === "add") {
    var polygon = new fabric.Polygon([{
      x: pos.x,
      y: pos.y
    }, {
      x: pos.x + 0.5,
      y: pos.y + 0.5
    }], {
      fill: 'blue',
      opacity: 0.5,
      selectable: false
    });
    currentShape = polygon;
    canvas.add(currentShape);
    mode = "edit";
  } else if (mode === "edit" && currentShape && currentShape.type === "polygon") {
    var points = currentShape.get("points");
    points.push({
      x: pos.x,
      y: pos.y
    });
    canvas.remove(currentShape);
    currentShape = new fabric.Polygon(points, {
      fill: 'blue',
      opacity: 0.5,
      selectable: false
    });
    canvas.add(currentShape);
  }
});

fabric.util.addListener(window, 'keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    if (mode === 'edit' || mode === 'add') {
      mode = 'normal';
      var points = currentShape.get('points');
      canvas.remove(currentShape);
      currentShape = new fabric.Polygon(points, {
        fill: 'blue',
        opacity: 0.5,
        selectable: true
      });
      canvas.add(currentShape);
    } else {
      mode = 'add';
    }
    currentShape = null;
  }
})
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

#### Solution #2

Recalculate the polygon dimensions every time, like it is done in the constructor of Polygon class. Excerpt from the code:

```
currentShape.set({
    points: points
});
currentShape._calcDimensions();
currentShape.set({
    left: currentShape.minX,
    top: currentShape.minY,
    pathOffset: {
        x: currentShape.minX + currentShape.width / 2,
        y: currentShape.minY + currentShape.height / 2
    }
});
currentShape.setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();
```

*Pros & Cons*: Better performance (probably noticeable on heavily loaded canvases), but you will have more code as you have to add it to both handlers.

You can check this out in the snippet below or in [this forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1fvxx6L/3/).

```js
/**
 * fabric.js template for bug reports
 *
 * Please update the name of the jsfiddle (see Fiddle Options).
 * This templates uses latest dev verison of fabric.js (https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/all.js).
 */

// initialize fabric canvas and assign to global windows object for debug
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// Do some initializing stuff
fabric.Object.prototype.set({
  transparentCorners: false,
  cornerColor: 'rgba(102,153,255,0.5)',
  cornerSize: 12,
  padding: 7
});

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE
var mode = "add",
  currentShape;

canvas.observe("mouse:move", function(event) {
  var pos = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
  if (mode === "edit" && currentShape) {
    var points = currentShape.get("points");
    points[points.length - 1].x = pos.x;
    points[points.length - 1].y = pos.y;
    currentShape.set({
      points: points
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});

canvas.observe("mouse:down", function(event) {
  var pos = canvas.getPointer(event.e);

  if (mode === "add") {
    var polygon = new fabric.Polygon([{
      x: pos.x,
      y: pos.y
    }, {
      x: pos.x + 0.5,
      y: pos.y + 0.5
    }], {
      fill: 'blue',
      opacity: 0.5,
      selectable: false
    });
    currentShape = polygon;
    canvas.add(currentShape);
    mode = "edit";
  } else if (mode === "edit" && currentShape && currentShape.type === "polygon") {
    var points = currentShape.get("points");
    points.push({
      x: pos.x,
      y: pos.y
    });
    currentShape.set({
      points: points
    });
    currentShape._calcDimensions();
    currentShape.set({
      left: currentShape.minX,
      top: currentShape.minY,
      pathOffset: {
        x: currentShape.minX + currentShape.width / 2,
        y: currentShape.minY + currentShape.height / 2
      }
    });
    currentShape.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});

fabric.util.addListener(window, 'keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    if (mode === 'edit' || mode === 'add') {
      mode = 'normal';
      currentShape.set({
        selectable: true
      });
      currentShape._calcDimensions();
      currentShape.set({
        left: currentShape.minX,
        top: currentShape.minY,
        pathOffset: {
          x: currentShape.minX + currentShape.width / 2,
          y: currentShape.minY + currentShape.height / 2
        }
      });
      currentShape.setCoords();
      canvas.renderAll();
    } else {
      mode = 'add';
    }
    currentShape = null;
  }
})
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Just a note: you can have a running example in your answer with Stack Snippets. Just use the Add Snippet button (or use Ctrl+M). That way, everything is right in your answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw this option, but since the other answers didn't provide one, I kind of inherited their format. :-) Thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: Actually, [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35154373/6083675) did use snippets. They're just hidden by default (click to show).

Comment: I stand corrected, didn't notice it before. And I have added snippets to my answer as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can fix the 'jumping' polygon by setting the originX and originY points on initialization.

```
        var polygon = new fabric.Polygon([{
        x: pos.x,
        y: pos.y
    }, {
        x: pos.x + 0.5,
        y: pos.y + 0.5
    }], {
        fill: 'blue',
        opacity: 0.5,
        selectable: false,
        originX: pos.x,
        originY: pos.y
    });
```

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ujefxh7w/48/

I don't know why the selection box is shifted.

**EDIT: found that reloading of the canvas object fixes the select box**

serializing, and loading the serialized objects does the trick:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(canvas);
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function() {
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ujefxh7w/50/