# Custom drawing tool with custom properties in Fabric Js

Tags: fabricjs

i am trying to create a custom drawing tool in the context of Fabric Js.
By custom i mean to apply to every drawn free line custom properties **e.g.:** 
1) - id of the created object; 
2) - who created it; 
3) - when is created 
4) - when is updated 
5)- etc.

---

For some other elements in the canvas that was more easy, e.g. for Circle, Rectangle, Triangle 
**Example (typescript, Angular code):**

---

```
export class Circle extends fabric.Circle implements ExtendedFabricOptions {
id: string;
createdBy: string;
editedBy: string;
createdOn: string;
updatedOn: string;

constructor(props: ICircleOptions) {
    super(props);
    this.id = props.id;
    this.createdBy = props.createdBy;
    this.editedBy = props.editedBy;
    this.createdOn = props.createdOn;
    this.updatedOn = props.updatedOn;
}
}
```

---

**And implementation of the code:**

```
onMouseDown(e: fabric.IEvent) {
const mousedownPointer: fabric.ICoords2d = {
  x: e.pointer.x,
  y: e.pointer.y
};

const object: Circle = new Circle({
  radius: 1,
  fill: this.fillColor,
  stroke: this.strokeColor,
  strokeWidth: this.strokeThickness,
  left: e.pointer.x,
  top: e.pointer.y,
  includeDefaultValues: false,
  id: this.whiteboardService.generateUUID(),
  createdBy: this.attendeeId,
  createdOn: (new Date()).getTime()
});
```

```
onMouseMove(e: fabric.IEvent, mousedownPointer: fabric.ICoords2d, object: Circle) {
    ... update Circle object here
}
```

```
onMouseUp(e: fabric.IEvent, object: Circle) {
    ... final logic here
}
```

---

But for Brush and Pencil is more complicated, since after setting the **"isDrawingMode"** property of the canvas (this.canvas.isDrawingMode = true;) to "true"
we have already creating an object, which behind the scene Fabric is attaching mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup event handlers.
On mouseup **"'mouseup' event, Fabric fires 'path:created' event and actually transforms just-drawn shape into a real fabric.Path instance!"**

So, based on this information - which would be the best approach to draw customized brushes with custom properties (id, creatdOn, UpdatedBy... etc...).
From which object is good my custom object to extend:
**For example:**

```
export class Highlighter extends fabric.BaseBrush implements ExtendedFabricOptions {
  uuid: string;
  createdBy: string;

  constructor() {
    ...
  }
}
```

**OR:**

```
export class Highlighter extends fabric.Path implements ExtendedFabricOptions
```

And based on extending the object, what will be the best way to create it:
If path there might be events for mousedown, mousemove and mouseup handling and updating the newly created instance of that Class.

Thank you in advance. That is very important topic since there are a lot of people trying to that the same behavior in the the most proper way!

---

Based on the answer for overriding mouse events of the **freeDrawingBrush** and including this.createdBy = 'some user id' and including other custom properties.
In fact these properties are applied to the class but not to the created instance. The goal is every created **brush object**, on selection to hold it's  own properties (it's own id, creator id, etc...)
With provided answer **"this"** in the mouse handler is:

[image]

**But on selection the same element doesn't have these properties:** 
[image]

Comment: I would use `PolyLine`, as long as you can push and pop points; write own UNDO and REDO; and on `mouse:move` you can push every 2nd or 3rd pixel to the `PolyLine` to make performance better. I wouldn't use `path` as long it's heavy. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/39028635/7132835 and updated fidlle for that answer http://jsfiddle.net/ysp82m57/

Answer (score 2):

Override mouse handlers of `freeDrawingBrush`. You need to define the same if you are changing `canvas.freeDrawingBrush`.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.freeDrawingBrush = new fabric.CircleBrush(canvas)
canvas.isDrawingMode = 'true';
var pathId = 0;

canvas.freeDrawingBrush.onMouseDown = (function(onMouseDown) {
  return function(pointer) {
    console.log('down');
    this.createdOn = Date.now();
    onMouseDown.call(this, pointer);
  }
})(canvas.freeDrawingBrush.onMouseDown);

canvas.freeDrawingBrush.onMouseMove = (function(onMouseMove) {
  return function(pointer) {
    onMouseMove.call(this, pointer);
  }
})(canvas.freeDrawingBrush.onMouseMove);

canvas.freeDrawingBrush.onMouseUp = (function(onMouseUp) {
  return function(pointer) {
    console.log('up');
    this.updatedOn = Date.now();
    onMouseUp.call(this, pointer);
  }
})(canvas.freeDrawingBrush.onMouseUp);

canvas.on('path:created',function({path}){
  path.createdOn = canvas.freeDrawingBrush.createdOn;
  path.updatedOn = canvas.freeDrawingBrush.updatedOn;
  path.pathId = pathId++;
  console.log(path.createdOn)
  console.log(path.updatedOn)
});
function onSelect(){
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
  canvas.selection = true;
}
function onDrawing(){
  canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
  canvas.selection = false;
}
canvas.on('object:selected',function(options){
console.log(options.target)
})
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<button onClick='onSelect()'>select</button>
<button onClick='onDrawing()'>drawing</button>
<canvas id='c' width=300 height=300>
```

Comment: Hi Durga, once again you are trying to help, very thankful for your help. The case is that these properties should be accessible on selection. They should be applied to every instance brush object and have to be of course unique.
I added comment above applying images, since here is not possible with additional information. if you have resolution, I will be very happy indeed :-). All the best!

Comment: @Virto111, that properties is for every instance, check snippet.

Comment: In fact i forgot to apply the last part of the code, namely **canvas.on('path:created')**, and that is applying custom properties to newly created object. It might be best to just extend classes since looks more clear, but at the moment that is not achieved :-).

Comment: @Virto111 You need to extend the brush class, you are currently using. so I don't think extending `fabric.BaseBrush` is enough, because it uses by the other brush classes. so your method also gets overriden there.

Comment: How can we select drawing automatically when mouse up event fire ?

Comment: @mayurkukadiya, canvas will fire 'path:created' event on mouse up, setActiveObject to that path.